# How to set Internet Explorer as the default web browser with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have a VBScript that makes Internet Explorer the default web browser.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 1200
WScript.Sleep 1200
WshShell.Run "%windir%\system32\control.exe /name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms /page pageDefaultProgram\pageAdvancedSettings?pszAppName=Internet%20Explorer"
WScript.Sleep 1200
WshShell.AppActivate "Set Program Associations"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys " "
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys " "
WScript.Sleep 2500
```

This script works perfectly, but I want to make the same with PowerShell.

I used the command `start-process("$ENV:WINDIR\system32\control.exe` to run the Control Panel, but I can't find out how to set the program associations like in the VBScript above.

Does anyone know how to set the program associations with PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main' -Name Check_Associations -Value 'yes'
```

Got it from [windowstechinfo.com](http://www.windowstechinfo.com/2016/03/fixed-cant-set-internet-explorer-as-the-default-browser.html)